# Adding a UIPageViewController to a subview, subview only shows edge of pageContentview

Tags: ios, objective-c, subview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to display an entire pageContentView within a SubView on a rootViewController. I'm able to see  the pageView but it doesn't auto-resize correctly to fit the SubView, it only shows a cutoff portion of the pageContentView

Here's what it looks like

[image]

Here's what it should look like

[image]

I can't figure out how to resize the pageView so it display correctly in a subView.

RootViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PageContentViewController.h"
@class PageContentViewController;

@interface CLDViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *subViewRoot;
- (IBAction)startWalkthrough:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pageTitles;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pageImages;

@property (strong,nonatomic) PageContentViewController *bounds;
@end
```

ViewDidLoad and required methods for UIPageViewController in RootController

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
 {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    _pageTitles = @[@"Over 200 Tips and Tricks", @"Discover Hidden Features", @"Bookmark Favorite Tip", @"Free Regular Update"];
    _pageImages = @[@"page1.png", @"page2.png", @"page3.png", @"page4.png"];

    // Create page view controller
    self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    //Trying to setup the pageViewContoller view to be inside the subview (subViewRoot)
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = self.subViewRoot.bounds;
    [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
    [self.subViewRoot addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];


}


    - (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (([self.pageTitles count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageTitles count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];
    pageContentViewController.imageFile = self.pageImages[index];
    pageContentViewController.titleText = self.pageTitles[index];
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;

    return pageContentViewController;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Page View Controller Data Source



- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.pageTitles count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return [self.pageTitles count];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 0;
}
```

PageContentViewController.m

-viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.imageFile];
    self.titleLabl.text = self.titleText;

}
```

Has anyone ran into this situation before? What did you do?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you using autolayout or struts + springs? Can you post a picture of the `PageViewController` within the storyboard?

Comment: It looks like turning off auto-layout did the trick. Thank you very much. What was actually happening though I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Added this as an answer below with some explanation.

Comment: Let me know if you have other questions. Basically you were setting the pageViewController's view's frame to an incorrect value.

Comment: I am also having similar issue with UIPageViewController. Please check my thread and let me know if you have suggestions with the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420396/adding-viewcontrollers-view-as-subview-to-uipageviewcontroller-in-ios-8-gives-w

Comment: i resolve my question with your question :D 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are setting the frame of your `UIPageViewController` to the frame of that 'subview' placeholder view, you need to make sure that the frame for the placeholder will be accurate by when the view is loaded. ViewControllers loaded from xibs don't generally have a useful frame until their view is added somewhere, and the same goes for their subviews. `viewWillAppear` is usually the soonest you can be sure your viewController's view to be set correctly.

Disabling auto-layout will work, but auto layout can be a nice feature once you learn how to use it. In this case, you can add constraints from `subViewRoot` to its parent view - Leading, Trailing, Top and Bottom. Control dragging from the `subViewRoot` to the parent is an easy shortcut.

Comment: Thanks again for the ultra-fast reply

I tried ctrl-dragging from the subview to the parent view and noticed a few options like you mentioned.(Trailing,Leading). I'm not sure about top and bottom. Just to try it out I selected (trailing,leading,top, and bottom) and it showed a cutoff pageView like before...here's a picture.

http://i.stack.imgur.com/Wa2Sv.png

Any idea why it might not be working, where: I use auto-layout and add the constraints you mentioned.

Comment: Your subview isn't extended to the parent view. The constraints will pin the subview whatever number of points it is away when you add the constraint.

Comment: Also, I don't know why you need that subViewRoot view. Just add the `UIPageViewController`s view as a subview of the viewController's view directly, using the viewController's bounds instead.

Comment: Won't that give me a full view then? My original goal was to resize the pageView so that it fits correctly in the subview or the root viewController's view. 

Is there a way to extend the subview (subViewRoot) to the parent view? PageViewContoller.?

Comment: Your picture looked like you did want the PageViewController's view to extend to its superview. I just don't understand the need for an extra view in-between the PageViewController's view and the RootViewController's view. Why not just add the PVC's view directly to the RVC's view?

Comment: So what I want is to be able to have a RVC that has multiple subViews.

For example here's what I'd like to have 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/61li6.png. So far the only way to do this is turning off Auto-layout...but instead of just turning it off and leaving the issue...I'd like to learn workarounds like you mentioned to leave auto-layout on and add constraints.

Comment: Going back to your original question, you said you wanted to display the entire contents of the PageViewController on the screen, but the content in your pages seems to be too large to fit. Were you really asking about shrinking the content down in size, not just the container for the content?

Comment: Yes I'm sorry for the confusion. Like you just said I'd like to shrink the content down to size(the pageView) so that it fits into a subview of a SuperView(RVC). Just like this:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/4rQiR.png

So far the only way I've been able to do that was turning off auto-layout in storyboard. 

If auto-layout is left on it looks like this : http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx0hn.png

The code is unchanged for both images above...only toggling auto-layout on and off.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my view laid out as I wanted using constraints on the PageContentViewController and also adding constraints to the SubView on the RootViewController. (As Acey suggested)

I did this by selecting "resolve auto-layout issues" --> Reset to suggested auto layout constraints.

Then also ctr-clking inside the view and setting width and height constraints. I can even change the orientation and the layout is what I expect.

for anyone struggling with this feel free to send a pm or comment here.